# How to create an in-memory SQLite database with Redshift data table schema in C# for unit testing?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a project with Redshift data table schemas and I want to write unit tests for it by using an in-memory database. I have tried creating an in-memory database using SQLite and copying the schema from Redshift, but it didn't work because of the different syntax Redshift uses, such as adding the public keyword before the table name.

Is there a way to create an in-memory database in C# that supports the Redshift syntax? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.